# how can i just increment a variable so that it store the value i want it to?

Tags: python-3.x

I an taking input from the user and the input will be more than 12 digits of number but i want the digits of the number individually so how can i increment the variable int like in the example below

```py
for i in range(len(number)):
    j = i + 1
    dj = int(number[i])
```

In this i is the ith digit and j is the number that will be appended with the d variable.

will this work ? I want it like `d1 = int(number[0])`
and so on so that i can do math operation on them.
there can be 12 - 16 digits in the number the user will give as input.
i have tried pre-defining the variables but that gave a error when the d16 digit did not get a number because of the len of input was 15.

Comment: Can you illustrate what you intend to do with an example/

Comment: i have illustrated what i want but again i want to take the digits, in the number that the user will give, individually so if the input is 15 digits i want 15 variables named d1,d2,d3 and so on and their values that in the number i get as input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this helps:

```
number=str(input())
for i in range(len(number)):
   j = i + 1
   exec(f'd{j} = int(number[i])')
```

Comment: This shall create variables starting from d1 to d_ based on number of digits in your value

Comment: hey can u tell me more about exec i am a beginner in python thanks

Comment: [Exec](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/exec) just executes the statement inside it. When you want to use variable values as names you do [f string](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/formatted-string-literals-f-strings-python/) on it with that value inside the curly braces({}).

Comment: Feel free to upvote and accept this answer if you find it useful!